# PHP PDO: Cannot use object of type 'x' as array

Tags: php, inheritance, pdo

Where 'x' is the child class name. I'm dealing with an issue with inheritance, and I'm well out of my depth. I'm getting the error:

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Mission as array` on line 12

```
class Mission extends Database {
protected $mission, $mission_id;

public function __construct($id) {
    parent::__construct();
    // Retrieve information from db
    parent::run('SELECT * FROM `missions` WHERE `mission_id`=:id LIMIT 1'); <!-- This is line 12 / Error is here
    parent::bind(':id', $id);
    $this->mission = parent::single();

    $this->mission_id = $id;
    return $this->mission;
}
```

Here is the constructor and the relevant method inside `Database`:

```
class Database {
public function __construct() {
    try {       
        // Create new DB Object 
        $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db,$this->user,$this->pass);

        // Set the error mode
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);        
    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        // Echo any errors. 
        echo $this->error = $e->getMessage();       
    }       
}

// Low level function
public function run($query, $runType = 'prepare') {
    try {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what the situation is?

Comment: where are you getting this error?

Comment: I mean which line, how are you implementing the class.

Comment: Whoops, Error is on line 12 (marked slightly off screen). I don't know enough about implementation to answer that question, sorry.

Comment: *Unless* you have another `run` function in your child, it's `$this->run` and not `parent::run`. You only use `parent::` if you want to *overwrite* a method from a parent class, and need to call the parent. (`parent::construct` is correct, as you *overwrite* the constructor)

Comment: also `$this->bind` and `$this->single()`

Comment: But if I use `$this->` instead of `parent::`, it seems as if I'm being asked to recursively call the child class' constructor function, not the parent's constructor function because I then receive the error `Missing argument 1 for Mission::__construct()`. Do I need to say `$var = new Database()` first?

Comment: `class Mission extends Database` - a "Mission" _is_ (most likely) not a "Database". Maybe instances of "Mission" are created from data stored in a database. But that doesn't call for deriving Mission from Database.